# Using the .= operator in PHP

Tags: php

This is a very basic question, but I'm trying to figure out some best practices. Is the `.=` operator just a way to shorten some code like this:

```
$a = 'John';
$b = 'Doe';
$n = $a.' '.$b';
```

to this:

```
$n = 'John';
$n .= ' Doe';
```

It seems like it makes sense, but I want to make sure I'm not missing anything. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got it. That's all it is.

```
$a .= $b;
```

Is equivalent to:

```
$a = $a . $b;
```

Just make sure that *both* variables are defined beforehand. Easy for people to forget when using the shorthand, but calling `$a .= $b` without `$a` defined shouldn't be done. You should always explicitly initialize variables.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! I'll accept it when it lets me :)

Answer (score 4):

You are not missing anything. The `.=` operator is just used for that.

The following pairs are equal:

```
$a = $a . 'b';
$a .= 'b';

$a = $a + 3;
$a += 3;

$a = $a - 3;
$a -= 3;

$a = $a / 3;
$a /= 3;

$a = $a * 3;
$a *= 3;
```

Answer (score 3):

To actually shorten some code like *this*:

```
$n = 'John';
$n = $n .' Doe';
```

your first code concats **three** strings and second only two
while to make your first code with .=

```
$n  = 'John';
$n .= ' ';
$n .= 'Doe';
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. It's just to write cleaner shorter code. Much like `+=` in javascript.

Comment: Though don't assume that += in PHP is the same as += in javascript :)

Comment: Yes, hence the `much like` not the `synonymous to`

Answer (score 0):

```
$forename = 'John ';

$surname = 'Bennet';

$forname = $forename . $surname;

echo $forname;
```

is the same as

```
$forename = 'John ';

$surname = 'Bennet';

$forename .= $surname;

echo $forname;
```

both outputs are the same:

```
John Bennet
```

Comment: both outputs are the same, but you're missing a space...they'd both output `JohnBennet`.