# Difference between $var and $var.=

Tags: php

What is the difference between `$var=` and `$var.=`?

I can't understand the difference between following statements:

```
$querypost .= "&showposts=$limit";
$querypost .= "&paged=$paged";
```

Comment: concatenation in the same way as += or -= but for strings

Comment: Your example is not in sync with your question. In your example both the cases are of concatenation hence the only difference between them is of value

Comment: in one word `$var.=?` is `$var = $var . ?`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using the .= operator in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209821/using-the-operator-in-php)

Answer (score 4):

That is concatenating the string so for example

```
$querypost = 'a';
$querypost = 'b'; // $querypost holds string 'b' now, 
                  // it will override the previous value


$querypost = 'a';
$querypost .= 'b'; // $querypost holds 'ab' now
```

If you want a friendly explanation, think `.` as a glue, it sticks two strings in a single variable instead of overriding the previous ones.

In your case, the query is concatenated, usually programmers do that when query strings are big or they are usually concatenated when the forms have optional parameters...

Comment: This is correct. The . before the equal sign is a string operator which concatenates the string. To see more information, check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php

Comment: sry didn't see, removing my comment

Answer (score 0):

See the difference

```
<?php

$testing = "Test ";
$testing  = "file"; 

//if we print `$testing` output is `file` $testing overriding the previous value


$testing = "Test ";
$testing  .= "file";     

//if we print `$testing` output is `Test file`. because **.** is a concatenate the previous value
?>
```

For eg in Query

```
$query  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$query .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $var = "a"; ////results var is no a
  $var .= "b" ////results var is now ab .= is equal to concatanation of variable or string.
```